# How to bundle vue-autonumeric with webpack version 2?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

When trying to bundle the `vue-autonumeric` package with Webpack **2**, the `AutoNumeric` dependency is not correctly found.

An alias exists in the configuration and works great when using webpack 3, however with webpack 2 and a blank project it fails with that error message:

```
Hash: 470e79379d7394141898
Version: webpack 2.7.0
Time: 135ms
           Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
./dist/bundle.js  12.7 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./~/vue-autonumeric/dist/vue-autonumeric.min.js 9.29 kB {0} [built]
   [1] ./src/vueAutonumericTest.js 120 bytes {0} [built]

ERROR in ./~/vue-autonumeric/dist/vue-autonumeric.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'AutoNumeric' in '/home/user/vueAutonum/node_modules/vue-autonumeric/dist'
 @ ./~/vue-autonumeric/dist/vue-autonumeric.min.js 1:82-104
 @ ./src/vueAutonumericTest.js
```

I tried adding:

```
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      AutoNumeric: 'node_modules/autonumeric/dist/autoNumeric.min',
    },
  },
```

to the `webpack.config.js` file for webpack 2, but that does not work as I expect it to.

Any ideas why and how to make it work for webpack version 3 *and* 2?

You can see more details about this problem in this [Github issue](https://github.com/autoNumeric/vue-autoNumeric/issues/4).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the umd wrapper in the bundle file of `vue-autoNumeric`:

```
if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory(require("AutoNumeric"));
else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define("VueAutonumeric", ["AutoNumeric"], factory);
else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["VueAutonumeric"] = factory(require("AutoNumeric"));
else
    root["VueAutonumeric"] = factory(root["AutoNumeric"]);
```

Obviously, `vue-autoNumeric` is dependent on an module named 'AutoNumeric'.

Maybe the `vue-autoNumeric` shall change webpack config or package dependencies list as the [Issue Comment](https://github.com/autoNumeric/vue-autoNumeric/issues/4#issuecomment-346633980) said.

Or, you can add `autonumeric` to your dependencies list and webpack will be able to find the missing module.

Comment: well, AutoNumeric is already defined as a dependency, but as 'externals' so that it does not get bundled. The comment you are refering to in the issue only states that 'it work for them', but when trying with a very basic project from scratch it does not unfortunately.